# Allow customer to remove order items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

hello i have this code which is supposed to remove an item from an order

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_remove_order_item_button', 10, 3 );
function display_remove_order_item_button( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) return;

    if( isset($_POST["remove_item_$item_id"]) && $_POST["remove_item_$item_id"] == 'Remove this item' ){
        wc_delete_order_item( $item_id );
        $order->calculate_totals();

    }

    echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style= "margin-top:12px;">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="remove_item_'.$item_id.'" value="Complete Cancellation" />
    </form>';
}
```

[image]

But when i press complete cancellation page refresh but nothing is removed & i refresh again nothing is removed

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code like:

- the condition `$_POST["remove_item_$item_id"] == 'Remove this item'` is always false.
- You need to remove the item using a hook before page start to load, to get the refresh. If not you will not see that the item has been removed and you will need to reload the page once.

So try the following instead:

```
// Displaying the form fields (buttons and hidden fields)
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_remove_order_item_button', 10, 3 );
function display_remove_order_item_button( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) )
        return;

    echo '<form class="cart item-'.$item_id.'" method="post" style= "margin-top:12px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="'.$item_id.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order->get_id().'" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="remove_item_'.$item_id.'" value="Complete Cancellation" />
    </form>';
}

// Processing the request
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'process_remove_order_item' );
function process_remove_order_item(){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) )
        return;

    if( isset($_POST['item_id']) && isset($_POST['remove_item_'.$_POST['item_id']]) && isset($_POST['order_id'])
    && is_numeric($_POST['order_id']) && get_post_type($_POST['order_id']) === 'shop_order' ) {
        // Get the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($_POST['order_id']) );

        // Remove the desired order item
        if( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') && is_numeric($_POST['item_id']) ) {
            $order->remove_item( absint($_POST['item_id']) );
            $order->calculate_totals();

            // Optionally display a notice
            wc_add_notice( __('Order item removed successfully'), 'success' );
        }

    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: Amazing as always Thanks